# How to programmatically see which conditions were not met in C++ when using logical AND (&&)?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I am trying to **efficiently** deduct which conditions caused an if statement to be overlooked by the program without using a sequence of if statements to verify each variable's relative integrity individually.

Is this possible?

```
bool state = false;
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int z = 3;

if(x == 0 && y == 1 && z == 2)    {
// Do something...
state == true;
}

if(state == false)    {

std::cout << "I did not execute the if statement because the following 
conditions were not met: " << std::endl;

/*Find a way to make the program output that z != 3 stopped the 
conditional from running without directly using if(z != 2)*/

}
```

Comment: If you want to know exactly which one failed, then why don't you do each condition separately?

Comment: Since you just want to inspect variable values, use a debugger to stop program execution at the desired location and print each variable with its help.

Comment: Print all the values in else part.
I think that will do .
In run time you can know which value is unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a counter as a "condition" between each of the conditions in the `if` to see when short-circuit evaluation of operator `&&` prohibits execution of the latter conditions:

```
int nrOfConditionFailing = 1;

if(x == 0 &&
   nrOfConditionFailing++ && y == 1 &&
   nrOfConditionFailing++ && z == 2)    {
    state = true;
}

if (!state) {
  cout << "failed due to condition nr " << nrOfConditionFailing << endl;
}
```

If you want to check all the conditions, you cannot do it in a single if-statement; Short-circuit evaluation of operator && will prevent the latter conditions to be even checked/evaluated if one of the former conditions evaluates to false.

However, you could do such a check as an expression that marks a bit in an unsigned int for each condition that is not met:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 3;

unsigned int c1 = !(x == 0);
unsigned int c2 = !(y == 1);
unsigned int c3 = !(z == 2);

unsigned int failures =
  (c1 << 0)
| (c2 << 1)
| (c3 << 2);

if (failures) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (failures & (1 << i)) {
            cout << "condition " << (i+1) << " failed." << endl;
        }
    }
}
else {
  cout << "no failures." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting and pretty useful basically nailed it... Any idea of applying a similar concept for when a multitude of conditions is not met?

Comment: No chance to detect if multiple  conditions are not met in a single `if`-statement; Short-circuit evaluation of operator `&&` will prevent the latter conditions to be even checked/evaluated if one of the former conditions evaluates to false.

Comment: Pretty good solution nonetheless for evaluating these single point failures. Thank you.

Comment: Multiple ++ increments in a single statement seems to be a questionable approach.  It makes sense from the && semantics, but I wonder if there's a UB problem?  Or maybe only if you actually use the value in a calculation in the statement?  Of course, you _are_ using the value -- that's why you have to set the counter variable to 1 at the beginning.

Comment: @DaveM. good idea but there is a guaranteed sequence point between each `&&` in most cases. Since all the types here are integral, the `++` is guaranteed to be evaluated before the next part of the statement, so no UB. However, this does *not* apply if `&&` is overloaded in this context, then it would be UB

Comment: This substantially differs from the original code in that there is no short circuit behaviour -- all tests are run even if the first fails.  (May or may not be what OP wants)

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you want to display to the end user, and not just while debugging, as suggested in the comments, you can design a simple data structure for yourself. It would be a list / vector / array of entries, each of which contain a) a value to compare against, b) a value to test, and optionally c) a description of the test.

Then simply iterate the list, and check if equality holds for all of them. If not, you can stop the flow of the programme and print out the description.

To more directly answer your question: no, there is nothing in C++ that would allow you to examine the results of previous statements. The statements and operations you see in the source code get compiled and possibly won't even be trivially recognisable among the assembly instructions. Being able to check the results would mean the data has to be stored somewhere, which would be an incredible waste of memory and processing time. That is why you have to do this yourself.

Comment: It now makes sense why this is something you'd have to do yourself. Didn't think about the resources.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

It is not possible in the way you were thinking about the problem. You can solve your problem instead by running each test individually, storing the result, and then identifying which of them were `false`:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,bool> > tests = {
       {"x==0",x==0}, // test name as a string followed by the actual test
       {"y==1",y==1},
       {"z==2",z==2}
    };

if(!all_of(tests.begin(),tests.end(),[](std::tuple<std::string,bool> &t) { return std::get<1>(t); }))
{
   std::cout << "The following tests failed: ";
   //remove all tests that passed
   tests.erase(
        std::remove_if(tests.begin(),tests.end(),[](std::tuple<std::string,bool> &t) { return std::get<1>(t); }),
        tests.end());
   //This will only print out the tests that failed
   std::transform(tests.begin(),tests.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),[](std::tuple<std::string,bool> &t) { return std::get<0>(t); });
   std::cout << std::endl;
} else {

  //what to do if all tests were true
}
```

This will evaluate all tests (i.e., it won't use `&&`'s short-circuiting) and print all the ones that failed. You could likely wrap this into a `class` to make this more generalizable and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The original code tests each variable individually. The `&&` series is exactly equivalent to a series of if...else statements. There's nothing inefficient about one compared to the other, and there's nothing "clever" about using some tricky solution that achieves the same end result as straightforward code.

I might write:

```
char const *reason = nullptr;

if(x != 0)
    reason = "x failed";
else if (y != 1)
    reason = "y failed";
else if (z != 2 )
    reason = "z failed";

if ( reason )
    std::cout << reason << '\n';
else
{
    // success code here...
}
```

Comment: Efficiency in this context pointed toward immediate scalability which your solution does not provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do something like the following to determine if a series of validity checks worked and to mark which ones failed.

```
unsigned long ulFlags = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int z = 3;

ulFlags |= (x == 0) : 0 ? 0x0001;  // if bit set then condition failed.
ulFlags |= (y == 1) : 0 ? 0x0002;  // if bit set then condition failed.
ulFlags |= (z == 2) : 0 ? 0x0004;  // if bit set then condition failed.

if(ulFlags == 0) {
    // Do something since all conditions are met and valid ...
} else {
    std::cout << "I did not execute if statement because: " << std::hex << ulFlags << std::endl;

    /* Find a way to make the program output that z != 3 stopped the 
      conditional from running without directly using if(z != 2) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same idea as some of the other answers, but with a template to simplify the syntax to use it. Stores all the individual checks in an `std::array<bool, N>` and one additional bool to be able to re-check the full statement without going through the individual results again.

No dynamic allocation is a plus as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... N>
struct what_failed {
    what_failed(N... n) : arr{n...}, status{(... && n)} {
        static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<N, bool>...>, "Only pass bools");
    }
    std::array<bool, sizeof...(N)> arr;
    bool status;
    operator bool() { return status; }
};

int main() {
    auto check = what_failed(2 == 5, 2 < 5, 2 > 5, 1 == 1);
    if (check)
        std::cout << "Check: All true";
    else {
        std::cout << "Check: ";
        for (auto c : check.arr)
            std::cout << c << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This requires c++17 due to fold expressions and template deduction in a constructor, but that can be worked around for c++11 with a couple of extra help-templates.